# Activity history - keep back stack but release memory

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

In my app, I have two activities. Let's call them `A` and `B`:

- `A` can launch another `A` activity or launch `B`
- `B` can launch `A` activities only

With this workflow, it's possible to open a long stream of `A` and `B` activities. It's even possible to open the same set of data recursively (and therefore keep going until the app crashes).

Sometime in the future, I'll probably implement "singleTask" [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) with my own activity history.

But for now, what I'd like to do is keep the back stack, but release memory for activities that are not in the foreground (ideally maintaining one active instance per `Activity`).

I thought that [clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) would do this for me, but my memory footprint gradually increases as I open one activity after the other. Is this expected behaviour, or does this indicate that I have a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

[Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624229/android-backstack-clear-but-keep-root) this may help you